# Processing incoming Postfix emails in a NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

In my application I need to process incoming emails. Each email is around 5MB and takes around 1 second to process. I need to handle spikes of 1000 emails per minute.

I am using Postfix to receive the emails. Each email is saved to a file, and then I call an ASP.NET 5 application via curl to notify that the file containing the email is ready to process, in a call like this:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/ready?file=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.eml
```

I assumed having a long running service with async methods (like this ASP.NET app) listening for the filenames was more efficient than calling a console application for each email received, but I may be wrong.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to process these emails than having a full web server running to serve these local requests.

Comment: Sounds like instead of an API call, this would be better served by a queue like RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus etc. Then you can scale the amount of queue consumers depending on your needs, or perhaps via serverless code such as AWS Lambda or Azure Functions.

Comment: Isn't Postfix a queue (or queues)?

Comment: But your ASP.NET app isn't a queue. Web sites are great for getting/saving data. Not good for batch processing. What actual work is the ASP.NET site performing for each email?